# Change job with EU Blue Card in Germany

Tags: germany, blue-card, visa-change

I started my Employment on February 2017, with EU Blue Card in Germany.
I want to switch jobs without re-authorization from the German Authorities. 
Can I do it now? (As it's been more than 18 months.)
Or should I wait for it to be 2 years? (On February 2019)

Comment: But still after two years I should go to ABH to change the employer name on zusatzblatt, or is it not needed anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change to a different company without going through the whole process, but you need to be aware of a few things.

Your new job must still be eligible for the § 19a visa. The job title should ideally be the same, or similar (i.e. something like *Senor Software Developer* and *Software Developer* or *Project Manager* and *Technical Project Manager*) is fine in my experience. If it's the same verbatim that makes it easier.

Your salary needs to still be high enough.

**You have to go to *Ausländerbehörde* and tell them in person**. If your title changed at all, they will give you a new accompanying paper. If it's literally the same, they will likely not give you a new one.

Keep in mind going there can take long. If you can, make an appointment. If you happen to be in Berlin, expect this to take a full day.

How long you've already worked has no bearing on this process. The Blue Card visa is not tied to a specific job, just the process of issuing it is tied to having a concrete job offer.

You can find information on the official website of the [*Bundesamt für Migration und Flüchtlinge*](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Infothek/FragenAntworten/BlaueKarteEU/blaue-karte-eu-node.html). Here's the relevant part:

> Any change of job during the first two years of employment requires the approval of the immigration authority (section 19a subs. 4 of the German Residence Act). Approval is subject to the same preconditions as initial issuance. If the minimum gross salary threshold has been raised during the intervening period, compliance with the new threshold must be proven. Holders of an EU Blue Card are obliged to inform the competent immigration authority if the employment for which the EU Blue Card was issued is terminated prematurely

Comment: This restriction shouldn't apply if you've already had the card for more than 2 years, or you've previously held the card in another EU state for more than 18 months. You should be able to change employer at your own will, and also be able to perform freelancer activities.

Comment: How long does this permission process with **Ausländerbehörde** takes in Munich? Or usually?

Comment: @JananathBanuka I don't know about Munich. In Berlin, the actual waiting would take a couple of hours usually, a few years ago. In Hannover it was much faster I have been told. I've only ever accompanied people, because I'm German myself. I would assume Munich is similar to Berlin. Best plan the better part of a full day.

Comment: Hi @simbabque, okay that's good to know. I was wondering it would take another month or so to get the final result from the **Ausländerbehörde**

Comment: @JananathBanuka ah sorry. No, the time I went with my friend to do it, we went up to this window when it was our turn, a bit like at the post office. We talked to a lady who refused to speak German (so I did most of the talking). She took the passport, the work contract, and the little paper, went away, and came back with everything a few minutes later. The little piece of paper was new, the rest stayed the same. Visa wasn't changed. It was all done in a single visit.

Comment: I can't speak for Munich (although I have heard better things about them than the Berlin _Auslaenderbehoerde_), but at the time (probably about 5 or 6 years ago) in Berlin the queue for non-appointment based stuff where you had to take a number was the same for asylum seekers and work visa issues. I recall going there before they opened in the morning and queuing outside. We both took a day off work to do it every time my friend had to go. Wooden benches on the inside, very sad environment. Take a book or your computer so you can work. You'll be there a while.

Comment: Hi @simbabque thank you for all these information. I still didn't get you. What I meant is, how long does it take so you have the approval from **Ausländerbehörde** that says you are permitted to change your employer?

Comment: @JananathBanuka it happens there, on the spot. You just wait a few minutes. It less an approval and more a rubber stamp. You take the new job, and then you go tell them. Unless you go from software developer to say chef, it will be fine. It still needs to fit your degree. If the job title is exactly the same, you don't even need to tell them. The point is not telling them about the exact job, it's about the job title being in your additional paper that goes with your blue card. So this is really making them aware of it, not asking their permission.

Comment: @simbabque thank you so much. I thought it takes another month or two for this process because when applying for the blue card, you have to wait about 2-3 months to get the Blue Card, and again if you are less than 2 years in Germany and changing employer, if getting permissions from **Ausländerbehörde** takes another month or two, this is really a caveat from finding another job or you have a job offer from the new employer already, they still have to wait another 2 months. Now it makes sense as you mentioned **Ausländerbehörde** takes 1 day, or 2 days tops. Have you been through this b4?

Comment: @JananathBanuka as I said, I am German. But a friend went through this several times (in fact, I know a few people who did) and I went with them a few times to do it. It was always trivial, as long as the new job fits your degree, they do it right there, within minutes. You just have to wait your turn, which can take long in some cities. I would assume in a small town the wait will be much faster. It helps to speak some German, especially in Munich. You will probably have noticed that by now. :)

Comment: Hi @simbabque is this something happened recently for your friend/s? Thank you so much for all the information :)

Comment: @JananathBanuka probably in 2016 and 2017, in Berlin. But the process should not have changed.

Comment: Thank you @simbabque :)